# My page won't dynamically load using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, dynamic

I am trying to dynamically change the content of my #nonMobileDiv in index.

Here's a part of my index.php:

```
<div class = "tiles">
    <a href="CreateNotebook.php" id="createNew">
    <img src="images/addSign.png" alt="Nature">
        <div class="titleMask">
           <h2>Create Notebook</h2>
        </div>
        <div class = "mask">
           <p>Create your own Notebook</p>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Here's my function:

```
 $('.tiles').on('click', 'a', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var url = $(this).attr('href');

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            success: function (data) {
            $('#nonMobileDiv').html(data); 
        }

        });

    });
```

I am wondering why it redirects to CreateNotebook.php even though I used the e.preventDefault(). I would love to hear any ideas.

Thanks.

Comment: after ajax, add a `return false;` line. i hope it will be solved.

Comment: where is the problem i see the code is firing the ajax correctly .. https://jsfiddle.net/1kfsx6rp/1/

Comment: _"I am wondering why it redirects to CreateNotebook.php even though I used the e.preventDefault()"_  Can you include `html` at Question? What is `'#nonMobileDiv'` element? Is the `window` refreshing, or is `'#nonMobileDiv'` `html` being set to `data`?

Comment: what data you are posting? as far as i see there is no hyperlink to the `.tiles` @keren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for all your comments and suggestions, apparently I have an open ended (incomplete and I think badly written) function written before my `$('.tiles').on('click', 'a', function (e) {` that causes the problem.